# tab key action in Notepad++ vs in Windows Notepad

Tags: notepad++, notepad

When I press the tab key at the beginning of a sentence in `Notepad++`, this happens:

[image]

(Note how the entire column of text is tabbed.)

When I do the same in `Windows Notepad` (the built-in app that's always been around in Windows), this happens:

[image]

(Note how only the first line of text is tabbed.)

I'm pretty sure that there's a config setting in my install of `Notepad++` that makes it behave differently. I actually prefer the way my `Notepad++` behaves, but I want to know how I can revert to the `Windows Notepad` way of handling the tab key action in case I need to for some reason in the future.

My question: what's the setting called.

Comment: `Note how only the first line of text is tabbed` actually the whole file in your screenshot is just a single line wrapped over when it's too long. By default Notepad doesn't do line wrapping (File > Word Wrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu : "Settings > Preferences > Editing > Check line wrap"

[image]